# pass in dynamic event label on google amp page

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

This is somewhat related to this question here [Pass dynamic event label in Google AMP analytics event tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425914/pass-dynamic-event-lable-in-google-amp-analytics-event-tracking)

However the answer doesn't quite answer what the user is looking for and I'm trying to do something similar. Just wanting to see if this is even feasible.  My analyst wants the event action and label to be the url and html or text of the clicked on anchor link respectively but can't find anywhere in docs or the git hub project where those values aren't static strings passed in.  In the variables for the amp page I don't see anything that would work either.  I'm doing a discovery so if it's not feasible that's ok but if it is I'd like to implement it.

```
    "trackAnchorClicks" : {
      "on": "click",
      "selector": "a",
      "request": "event",
      "vars": {
        "eventCategory": "click",
        "eventAction": "Link Clicks",
        "eventLabel": "link"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass dynamic event label in Google AMP analytics event tracking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425914/pass-dynamic-event-label-in-google-amp-analytics-event-tracking)